# Why isn't cabal-install upgrading itself?

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install

When I do a cabal update I get the following output:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
```

So I run

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

However, after I run

```
cabal update
```

I still get the same note about a new version of cabal-install.

When I run

```
cabal --version
```

I get the following output:

```
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library
```

However, in

```
/~/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib
```

I only have these two items:

```
Cabal-1.16.0.3      cabal-install-1.16.0.2
```

Why would I have this inconsistency?

I'm running on Mac OSX v. 10.8.3

Comment: You probably don't have `cabal`'s `bin` directory in your path.  `cabal` installs all binaries from Hackage into `~/.cabal/bin` on Linux (I'm not sure what the equivalent on OSX is), and `cabal-install` is no exception.